# Why unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER) return error? (linux)

Tags: c, linux

This is my fairly simple code:

```
 #define _GNU_SOURCE
 #include <sched.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(){
   int res= unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER);
   printf("res:%d\n",res);
   perror("error");
   return 0;
}
```

Why does the code always fail (return -1)?

I'm on `Ubunto 13.04` this is my kernel version and other details:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.10.37-031037-generic #201404141035 SMP Mon Apr 14 14:55:40 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

- errno returns `Invalid argument`

this is the output of the program :

```
res:-1
error: Invalid argument
```

Comment: What's the value of `errno`?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely because your kernel is not configured to support `CONFIG_USER_NS`.

I reckon running the command:

```
unshare -U
```

also produces the same error on your machine.

You can verify that with the command:

```
grep CONFIG_USER_NS /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: `grep CONFIG_USER_NS /boot/config-$(uname -r)` return nothing , and `unshare`  seems like it's work...

Comment: @P.P could you confirm this: I believe there's a typo in your post. CLONE_NEWUSER depends on CONFIG_USER_NS being enabled, so I think there's a "not" missing there.

Comment: @domen Indeed. Corrected it. Thanks.